# WCF Rest parameters in http body

Tags: wcf, rest

Is there a way to accept text parameters in the HTTP body from a WCF service?

For example, `name=aabbcc&age=14`

Comment: yes you can send the json/xml data which contains these values.

Comment: No there is message queue system in place which sends parameters as text not as json or xml. example event={jsonobject}

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can send parameters using both **GET** and **POST**. If you are sending one or two parameters like you have posted in your question then you can use **GET** but the disadvantage is that your data will be appended in **query string** and it will be visible.

```
[OperationContract]
[Webget(UriTemplate = "/name={name}&age={age}")]
string MyGETMethod(string name, string age);
```

And in your implementation:

```
string MyGETMethod(string name, string age)
{
    return "You entered Name: "+name+" and Age: "+age;
}
```

To test this method. Open your browser and write url like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/YourServiceName/name=myname&age=10
```

For **POST** method, make your **OperationContract** like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST" , UriTemplate = "nameandage", RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.JSON)]
string MyPOSTMethod(string name, string age);
```

For this, you have to make POST Client.